# Unable to make direct TCP connections on blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

In my blackberry application I'm establishing network connection by appending ;deviceSide=true  in the url. It is working fine on simulator but its not working on device. I've correct APN settings as other third party apps are running fine. 
Please let me know the possible reason for this issue!!!

Comment: More information or code snippets would help.

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary that your app always connect via direct TCP.
For taking care all types of networks available in blackberry for your app refer this article.
[How to programmatically connect to the internet in blackberry](http://www.vimviv.com/kb.php?id=32)

Comment: Thanks for replying,
Actually I'm using Airtel network in India (Noida), but on connecting through direct TCP method it throws Tunnel Failure exception. On airtel it is required to enable MobileOffice services to use this method which I've already activated, still my app is unable to connect through network

Comment: are you using a correct URL with connection string?
URL+;deviceside=true;apn=airtelgprs.com

Comment: Yes I'm using URL+;deviceside=true;apn=airtelgprs.com  for opening a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

[Network Diagnostic Tool](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Network_Diagnostic_Tool.html?nodeid=1450596&vernum=0)

download this network diagnostic tool developed by RIM and check weather direct TCP is working or not in your mobile.